# I can't print my code on seperate lines- python 3.4.1

Tags: python, list, printing, newline

```
#Creating empty list
movies = []

#Creating variable that will control number of DVD titles we can enter
dvds = 0

#Creating the while loop
while dvds < 1000000: #This ensures that a large amount of DVD titles can be entered depending on user's personal DVD collection
       print ("Please enter a DVD from your personal collection- press the 'enter key' to stop adding movies")
       next = input("> ")

       #If conditional statement to verify input
       if len(next) > 0 and next.isalpha():
              movies.append(next)
              dvds = dvds + 1 or dvds==''

       else:
              break

       print (movies)
```

Comment: Why would you use a break?

Comment: I haven't done error handling yet. I'm replacing break with an error message. But thanks. @MalikBrahimi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Print a List, you can use

```
for movie in movies:
    print(movie)
```